# Set up push notifications on the new developer.microsoft.com website?

Tags: azure, notifications, uwp

I want to follow the tutorial ["Get started with Notification Hubs for Universal Windows Platform apps"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) and there (and on all other resources I found) it is written:

> Back on the Windows Dev Center page for your new app, select Services,
>   select Push notifications, and then select WNS/MPNS.

Unfortunately, I am unable to select "Push notifications" as this entry does not exist. Where other people see "Push notifications" I see "XBox Live":

[image: Where is the menu item Push Notifications?]

Has someone an idea how to finish this tutorial with the new website? Or more generally - how to set up notifications on this new website? Is there nowadays a totally different approach? Is this step no longer needed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. These steps are just not necessary:

> 8. Back on the Windows Dev Center page for your new app, select Services, select Push notifications, and then select WNS/MPNS.
> 9. Select New Notification.
> 10. Select Blank (Toast) template, and then select OK.
> 11. Enter a notification Name and Visual Context message, and then select Save as draft.

If someone is interested, the notification entry has moved to a different location:

[image]

You can click on "Live Services Site" to get to your app's development area where you get the secrets you need for notifications or you go [there](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) in some other way.

By the way, a great resource if anyone is interested in push notifications for xamarin android, xamarin ios or uwp is "[Microsoft Azure Notification Hub with UWP and Xamarin](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-VisualStudio-Dev/Microsoft-Azure-Notification-Hub-with-UWP-and-Xamarin)".